# How to Web Scrape the Site in Excel/Google Sheets?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How should I scrape this webpage https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/asian-paints-ltd/asianpaint/500820/ and specifically need the ROE figure which is mentioned in the table?

I used the following code in Excel. I don't know much about Google Sheets Scraping

```
 Sub FetchData()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/asian-paints-ltd/asianpaint/500820/", Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
        .Name = "www"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

I was not able to fetch the data properly.

Any suggestions/help on this? Need the ROE figure rest of it is not required.

Comment: Two major tags `excel` and `vba` are missing.

Comment: The question is too broad as it apparently is asking about features that work very differently on two spreadsheet apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the API that the page uses it much faster. You can use powerquery to handle json response, a json parser or just use split. Put code in a standard module and link to a button if you want to refresh at a button press.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim s As String, ids(), i As Long
    ids = Array(500820, 500312, 500325, 532540)
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(ids) To UBound(ids)
            .Open "GET", "https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/ComHeader/w?quotetype=EQ&scripcode=" & ids(i) & "&seriesid=", False
            .send
            s = .responseText
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = Split(Split(s, """ROE"":""")(1), Chr$(34))(0)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this works well and how about if I want to go with more than one company data? How should I go about that?

Comment: You would use a loop. What are the different companies? You’d need to concatenate  the appropriate id into the api call.

Comment: To be honest I am not much into VBA. Like I mentioned earlier plain stuff is doable by me. But not much in detail I can get into with this thing

Comment: For example 500312, 500325, 532540

Comment: https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/tata-consultancy-services-ltd/tcs/532540/

Comment: https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/oil-and-natural-gas-corporation-ltd/ongc/500312/

Comment: https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/reliance-industries-ltd/reliance/500325/

Comment: Well Understood now. Thanks!

Comment: I did play with the code since this one was working smooth. As I added other variables to it which has been displayed in that box. But I am stuck with other variables namely the Results and Shareholding Pattern table. Has it to do with the api link or something else? I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Please post a new question add your current code and drop me the link here.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way I find easier to get that particular value. Once the `for loop` detects `ROE`, it will go after the required value and exit the loop as they both are within the same parent node.

```
Sub FetchData()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, post As Object
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, elem As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/asian-paints-ltd/asianpaint/500820/"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
    End With

    For Each post In Html.getElementsByTagName("td")
        If post.innerText = "ROE" Then
            Set elem = post.ParentNode.querySelector(".textvalue")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next post

    [A1] = elem.innerText
End Sub
```

References to add:

```
Microsoft Html Object Library
Microsoft Internet Controls
```

Comment: I'm afraid on how should I add couple of those references?

Comment: Check out [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mX7VmVljKVQ) to learn how to.

Comment: Many thanks! I will dig deeper into this. Thanks once again

Comment: Done! Once again thanks a lot. Simplifies a lot for me.

Comment: SIM ~ it gives me Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: I tried few times but could not reproduce the error. However, it all depend on your internet speed as it sometimes take some extra time for the element to load properly. In such cases a little wait helps. Try using this `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")` line between `End With` and `For Each post` within the above script.

Comment: It is working now. Also I added multiple company links to it.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, that won't be possible because the site is controlled by JavaScript and Google Sheets can't understand/import JS. you can test this simply by disabling JS for a given link and you will see a blank page:

[image: 0]

all you can get is what you see:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/asian-paints-ltd/asianpaint/500820/"), 5000, 15)
```

Comment: Manually entering the data works, I guess, at the end of the day when automating doesn't help. Although I did notice they changed the site features. I do happen to web-scrape other things on the site quite easily, but this seemed hard to crack. What you mentioned explains it all. Thanks